# jQuery - change src of image

Tags: jquery

const target = $(this); did the trick.

I have this code that runs through every image with the class logochange and then it should get a new src from Ajax.

```
$('.logochange').each(function() {
        target = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getCompanyLogo.php',
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                pno: target.attr("data-pno")
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(target.attr("data-pno")+' '+data+' '+$(this).attr('src'));
                //$(".bodytext").html(data);
                // Parse the returned json data
                if(data != 0){
                    console.log('skift img');
                    target.attr("src", data);
                    //target.parent().html(data);
                }
            }
        });
        
    });
```

I get a real url in return from the ajax, but target.attr("src", data); does not work. The line below works it removes the img-tag and writes the new image url.

I can't figure out why it won't work.

Comment: Is it the same URL each time? If yes, your image is cached.

Comment: No, the first url and second url are not the same. But I will try to add a timestamp to the new url.

Comment: Off topic: You no longer need to concatenate console.log into a single string, use comma separated and if any are objects they'll be output with properties:  `console.log(target.attr("data-pno"), data, $(this).attr('src'));`

Comment: Can you include an example of `data`?  Add debugging, eg `$(this)[0].nodeName` - in the success: callback, `this` is not the outer `this` (easiest way to think of it is every time you do `function() {` you get a different `this`) so `$(this).attr('src')` will not be the same as `target.attr("src")` - but you're not using `$(this)` to *set* the src, only in the debug.

Comment: The issue is simple, you are using a global variable so only the last loop is getting the update image. `target = $(this);` should be `const target = $(this);` Always declare your variables. A tool like eslint will pick up these errors.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try async function.
And are you sure getting data ? you can try writing to response console log.

Like this;

```
$('.logochange').each(async function() {
        target = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getCompanyLogo.php',
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            data: {
                pno: target.attr("data-pno")
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(target.attr("data-pno")+' '+data+' '+$(this).attr('src'));
                //$(".bodytext").html(data);
                // Parse the returned json data
                if(data != 0){
                    console.log('skift img');
    console.log("imgData:" + data);
                    target.attr("src", data);
                    //target.parent().html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: In this line: console.log(target.attr("data-pno")+' '+data+' '+$(this).attr('src')); I get first and secon right, but the last one is undefined.